# XKB - Get Caps Lock mask

Tags: c++, xlib, capslock

I've been trying to write a program that enables/disables different locks (num lock, caps lock, scroll lock), but I've been having issues with caps lock. For some reason, XKB doesn't know about  "CapsLock" vmod, while it does know about ScrollLock and NumLock.

How do I get the caps lock mask?

---

My function is this (nearly directly copied from numlockx):

```
unsigned int KL_Modifier::get_mask(const char* name) {
    XkbDescPtr xkb;
    if ((xkb = XkbGetKeyboard(this->disp, XkbAllComponentsMask, XkbUseCoreKbd)) != NULL) {
            int i;
            unsigned int mask = 0;
            if (!xkb || !xkb->names) {
                    mask = 0;
                    goto end;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < XkbNumVirtualMods; i++) {
                    char* mod_str = XGetAtomName(this->disp, xkb->names->vmods[i]);
                    std::cout << mod_str << " " << name << std::endl;
                    if (mod_str != NULL && strcmp(name, mod_str) == 0) {
                            XkbVirtualModsToReal(xkb, 1 << i, &mask);
                            //break;
                    }
            }
end:
            XkbFreeKeyboard(xkb, 0, True);
            return mask;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I call it like this:

```
unsigned int mask = this->get_mask("CapsLock");
assert(mask != 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what my problem was, but I found a solution: Use `XkbKeysymToModifiers` instead, like this:

```
unsigned int mask = XkbKeysymToModifiers(display, XK_Caps_Lock);
```

Where `display` is a `Display*`. With this solution, I was able to switch `XK_Caps_Lock` to `XK_Num_Lock` and `XK_Scroll_Lock` for the other locks.